# Traefik.io and Docker - How to allow Requests only for one specific host

Tags: docker, prometheus, traefik

I am running docker-swarm with traefik.io as the front-end reverse proxy. 
I have one microservice which is providing a metric url for prometheus. Prometheus is also running as a docker service within the docker-swarm.  The metric URL is not protected.

```
http://myservice:8080/api/metrics
```

How can I configure traefik.io in a way, that this URL is only accessible by prometheus docker container and blocked for all other requests (internal and external)?

Example:

```
prometeus  -->   http://myservice:8080/api/metrics  = OK
internet   -->   http://myservice:8080/api/metrics  = BLOCKED
some-other-container  -->    http://myservice:8080/api/metrics  = BLOCKED
```

But I want to block only this one resource (/apit/metrics). The service in general should be routed by traefik.io in the default way.

Is this possible with the rule  *traefik.frontend.headers.allowedHosts*? Can someone give an example how this should be set?